# How to get Wordpress attachments to work for existing images inside the Media Library?

Tags: wordpress

I want to display the images from each Wordpress post on a separate page.

When using `get_children` (or `get_posts`) the `'post_type' => 'attachment'` only works if I've just uploaded an image (via WP's 'ADD MEDIA > UPLOAD FILES') to that particular post.

It does not work if I add an existing image to a post that's already in my WP MEDIA LIBRARY).

Is there anyway for `'attachment'` to work for existing (already uploaded) images?

See my test function:

```
function echo_first_image($postID){
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'post_parent' => $postID
    );
    $attachments = get_children( $args );
    if($attachments){
        echo'YES';   // test answer
    }else{
        echo'NO';   // test answer
    }
}
```

EDIT: each 'post_type' that is an 'attachment' has a single 'post_parent' - does this mean an attachment can ONLY have a single parent?

Answer (score 0):

Currently as of writing, Wordpress 4.1 does not include multi-parent attachments because the database relationship is one-to-one, not one-to-many. You would have to find a plugin, or write your own to get around that.